# Why aren’t Ned Leeds and Peter Parker still friends?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, spider-man-no-way-home

Ned and Peter Parker were friends before the whole Spider-Man Incident.

Then, during No Way Home,

> Dr. Strange makes everyone forget Peter Parker is Spider-Man. Which has the adverse affect that MJ and Ned Leeds to forget him completely. However, as I said before, Ned and Peter were friends before Peter became Spider-Man (Citation: Peter invites Ned over to build LEGO Death Star, the day he becomes Spider-Man)

Why isn’t Ned still friends with Peter Parker?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Looks like your question is factually incorrect in several ways.  Thats not what the spell did at all.  And that wasn't the day he became spider man either.

Comment: @JK., I guess I misinterpreted how the spell worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The spell [makes everyone forget that Peter Parker ever existed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258602/did-dr-stranges-final-spell-have-physical-effects?rq=1), not just the fact that he's Spider-Man. As per [the screenplay](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Spider-Man-No-Way-Home-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf):

> PETER: They’re coming here because of me, right? Because I’m Peter
> Parker? So cast a new spell, but this time make everyone forget who
> Peter Parker is. Make everyone forget... me.
>
> DR. STRANGE: No.
>
> PETER: But it would work, right?
>
> DR. STRANGE: Yeah, it would work. But you gotta understand that would mean that everyone
> who knows and loves you, we... *[voice catches, then]* We’d have no
> memory of you. It would be as though you never existed.
>
> PETER: ...I know. *[resolved]* Do it.

M.J. knew Peter before she figured out he was Spider-Man too (they were academic decathlon teammates!), and she forgets him just like Ned. We can assume his school forgets him, as at the end of the movie he has a book that suggests he's studying independently for his high-school diploma. If Aunt May had (spoiler) survived, even she wouldn't recognise him.

He's nobody now!